# how to get data from mutiple collections in mongodb sametime

Tags: node.js, mongodb

these are my collections

```
userscollection { "_id": "5bb4a954f49790893c60b096", "name": "vamsi", "email": "vamsi.sunny@gmail.com", "password": "uixzBOfZnC", "phoneno": 9032610826, "date": "2018-02-08T18:30:00.000Z", "type": "angular", "__v": 0, "Role": 2, "status": "active" }, studentcollection { "_id": "5bb5bb223d6f37a134747f4d", "result": "pass", "date": "15/10/2018", },
```

there are two collections users and students.how to get the name,email,password from the userscollection and the result,date from the result collection using the  nodejs and mongoose schemas

Comment: Please read `$lookup` in MongoDB Help you. reference Link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `$ref` while defining both mongoose schema.
and use

```
db.getCollection('mainCollection').find().populate('dependentCollection')
```

populate is not a native mongoDb method, so it will not work in shell. it works with mongoose only.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/

The other way is to use aggregate query there you can use `$lookup`, that works as a left outer join in both of the collection.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/
Thanks!!!